# using transparency value over imagesc

Tags: matlab, plot

When I plot a patch with transparency < 1 over an image created with imagesc (Matlab R2012a), I get something that looks like lots of "tick lables", or numbers over the image along the axes. The following code reproduces the problem:

```
imagesc(rand(10,20))
hold on
patch([5 5 15 15],[3 7 7 3],'r','facealpha',.5)
```

Is this a bug, or is there a way to do it properly?

**EDIT**
The numbers disappear if I set `set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])`, so it is indeed tick-related. I would of course prefer having ticks on my figure.

[image: imagesc with numbers on it]

Comment: I just tried on 2012b and it does not happen. Does this also happen after you do a fresh start of matlab? I would guess that you have some old axis that cause the problem.

Comment: It still happens after restart, and for new figure.

Comment: If you change the renderer to `zbuffer`, does the problem still happen? i.e. `set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')`

Comment: Can you verify that your XtickMode and YtickMode are set to auto and that your xlim and ylim make sense?

Comment: I can verify that doesn't happen on 2012b, why not upgrade your version of matlab?

Comment: @Jonas: This makes the tick labels appear ok, but the transparency is now 1 no matter what value I use.
DennisJaheruddin: Yes to all your questions.
slayton: I use a university-based server license, upgrading is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of graphical artifact is usually related to the renderer. Particularly the OpenGL renderer seems to mess up on certain combinations of Matlab release, graphics card, and operating system.

The standard workaround is to [change the renderer from OpenGL to zBuffer in the figure properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html), which is achieved via the command

```
set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')
```

Unfortunately, OpenGL is the only renderer that supports transparency, so this solution won't work for you.

As a possible alternative workaround, you can switch from hardware to software OpenGL renderer via the command

```
opengl software
```

Check the [help on opengl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) to find out how to set this up in case you're in a *nix environment.